# NSTimer Delegate Selection

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, delegates, nstimer

I am trying to create a framework for all of the custom objects and views that I have made and use often, by creating custom delegate classes and custom objects. Everything has gone well except when trying to get NSTimers to call the correct method inside of the delegate class.

Here is the basic setup.

```
-(void) startTimers {
    NSTimer *timer1 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSTimer *timer2 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(doSomethingElse:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I can easily just call this method and whatever, but when this time fires it does not call the method I defined as the selector. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the delegate value and which class it is making as the delegate.

Note the file I am writing in is a subclass of UIView, which is set up to be a delegate using the @protocol tags and all of that.

What should I set as the target when defining my timers to get them to call the correct methods.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of what I am doing:

ExampleView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ExampleViewDelegate;

@interface ExampleView : UIView {
    NSTimer *timer;
}
-(void) initWithStuff:(id)stuff andFrame:(CGRect)frame;
-(void) testTimer;
@end

@protocol ExampleViewDelegate

-(void) someDelegateFunction;
@end
```

ExampleView.m

```
#import "ExampleView.h"

@implementation ExampleView


-(id) initWithStuff:(id)stuff andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(testTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    return self;
}

-(void) testTimer {
    NSLog(@"Timer Fired");
}

@end
```

If you add this custom view into a viewcontroller it will never call that testTimer function and print "Timer Fired" So what I am thinking is that when I set the delegate for this timer, it is actually setting it to something else. Any ideas?

Comment: You are defining startTimers in a subclass of UIView or UIViewController?

Comment: Timers don't have delegates; what protocol are you talking about? I would guess that you've got a typo between the name of your method and the selector you're passing. Are you getting a crash?

Comment: an edit has been submitted, please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSTimer *timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Notice the method is called "scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval"

Comment: Well spotted. That's indeed the problem. `timerWithTimeInterval:...` is a valid method, but doesn't add the timer to the run loop as `scheduledTimer...` does, which means the timer is created but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wow, I could not feel more stupid right now. Good spot there Vinnie. I have use NSTimers so many times before, and had them working, but for some reason this time I was defining it incorrectly. I guess that is what you get for programming at 2 AM :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I only knew because I have had the exact same time-wasting experience a few months back. You're in good company.