# NSTimer not firing

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this NSTimer wont fire. here is all of the code that appears relevant (at least to me)

```
- (IBAction)connectClick:(id)sender
{
    if (connected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Disconnecting");
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        connected = NO;
        [Connect setStringValue:@"Connect"];
        NSLog(@"Finished\n");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connecting");
        timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        //[timer fire]; tested this line. same results
        [Connect setStringValue:@"a"]; 
        connected = YES;
        NSLog(@"Finished\n");
    }
}

- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    NSLog(@"Fireing event");
    //[self resetRequest];
    //[spinner startAnimation:nil];
    //[request startAsynchronous];
}
```

I have read the apple docs, and other questions, but I cannot figure it out. It does not even call `timerDireMethod:` once. I have heard this could be caused by different threads, but as far as I can tell, I am not using multiple threads.

All ideas welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTimer not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752234/nstimer-not-firing)

Comment: Is there some reason that you're using NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode instead of NSDefaultRunLoopMode?

Comment: Sorry Its late here. I just noticed that and was going to add that to the question. but yes NSDefaultRunLoopMode worked. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTimer Delegate Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288965/nstimer-delegate-selection)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for Mac OS X:

> You must add the new timer to a run loop, using addTimer:forMode:.
>   Then, after seconds seconds have elapsed, the timer fires, sending the
>   message aSelector to target. (If the timer is configured to repeat,
>   there is no need to subsequently re-add the timer to the run loop.)

Personally, I typically use `+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]`

Also note that if you call this method on a background thread, or in a block operation that runs in a background queue, the `NSTimer` gets destroyed when the background thread does. So be sure you are running it on the main thread or in the main queue if appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I used this but it's still not firing.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation for the method you're using, [+timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a):

> You must add the new timer to a run loop, using addTimer:forMode:.
>   Then, after seconds seconds have elapsed, the timer fires, sending the
>   message aSelector to target.